# RStudio Viewer throws error

Tags: r, rstudio

### Issue

Some versions of RStudio throw an error in the Viewer pane of my javascript widget, and some don't.

---

### Code

I've created a [htmlwidget](http://htmlwidgets.org/) for my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package that plots a Google Map.

To reproduce this issue (if indeed it is an issue on your system) you can simply run this code

```
devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
library(googleway)
google_map(key = '')  ## you don't need a key to see the error
```

But if you want to view a map, you'll need a [Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)

---

### Description

The issue I'm having is that on some versions of Rstudio the map shows in the *Viewer* pane, and in others it doesn't.

When I "inspect" the Viewer (right-click > inspect > console), I get the error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'i'. Expected either 'in' or 'of' in enumeration syntax.

[image]

Which links to a `for` loop inside the javascript (see screenshot and the [source code](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/google_map.js#L130))

[image]

---

This morning I upgraded Rstudio on the system that caused the error, but it's still giving the error.

The following two screenshots show two different Macs (both running OS Sierra) with Rstudio, with examples of

- Rstudio v1.0.143 - not working
- Rstudio v1.0.136 - working

[image]

[image]

Why does some versions of RStudio throw the error, and some don't?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its probably better asked on the RStudio support channels.

Comment: not sure but `let` is ES2015 so older browsers will not know how to use it.  you can try the old `var` instead.

Comment: @timelyportfolio - that could have something to do with it - changing to `var` "fixes" that issue, but then stops at another: `data.find(x => x.id == _id)`, which I suspect is also causing a similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/5977215

Comment: @timelyportfolio - I think you've hit the nail on the head; changing `let` to `var`, and `.find(x => ...)` to a more primitive loop has solved the issue!

Comment: However, I'm still not sure *why* the `let` and `.find()` worked in an older version of Rstudio...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@timelyportfolio's suggestion was instrumental (again!) in finding the solution.

I'm not convinced the issue was purely due to Rstudio, or there are other factors involved, especially as the widget works on an older version, but for now I'll leave this as the solution.

The `let` in the line

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.calls.length; i++) {
```

is not supported in all browsers, so changing it to `var` worked for that line (and all the lines that use a `let`).

I was also using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/5977215) for finding values in an array

```
data_.find(x => x.id === _id)
```

Which again is not supported in all browsers, so reverting to

```
function findById(source, id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i].id === id) {
      return source[i];
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

seems to resolve that issue too.

et voila!

[image]

Comment: if you really wanted, you could transpile with `reactR::babel_transform()`.